# Ground state degeneracy and quantum phase transition

Tags: quantum-entanglement, phase-transition

According to the idea in the [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.155138) of Wen, the quantum phase transition happens between long range entanglement states that can not be connected by LUs.

I am thinking about the following scenario:

We have a certain quantum system and two different Hamiltonians $H_0$,$H_1$, whose (degenerated) ground states ($\psi_{i}^{1},\psi_{i}^{2},...\psi_{i}^{N_i}$ as the ground states of $H_i$) are all states with long range entanglement.

My question is:

Is it possible that for some ground state pairs, $\psi_{0}^{m}$ and $\psi_{1}^{l}$ for $H_0$ and $H_1$ respectively, are not connected by LUs, but some other ground states, $\psi_{0}^{p}$ and $\psi_{1}^{q}$, are connected by LUs?

If this is possible, how do we determine if there is a quantum phase transition between these two configurations? Or this is really dependent on the specific ground state the system stays in?